# How to get list of hosts reporting to a data source in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

In my Grafana setup, there are a number of hosts missing. I see that Prometheus is running on those hosts and collecting metrics but I don't see them in Grafana.

I would like to know if the data source in the Grafana side is receiving the metrics at all. Is it possible (from the Grafana side) to list all hosts that a data source is reporting info from?

EDIT: the "data source" above, refers to the Grafana's data source object: https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/

Basically I want to know why Grafana is not seeing some of the hosts since all hosts have Prometheus running.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your question. Prometheus is the data source and is usually collecting server metrics from node exporter. Are those what you are referring to ?

Comment: @MichaelDoubez Yes, by data source I meant the object in Grafana. See my question's edit.

Comment: So you have a data source per prometheus instance. How do you know some of them are not reporting data ?